# C: finding occurrences of bytes in a block of memory

Tags: c, pointers, byte

I am trying to write a function that uses only pointer-based logic to search through a region of memory (`blockAddress`) for a certain byte (`Byte`), counts the occurrences, and stores the offsets in an array (`pOffsets`). Here is what I have so far:

```
// blockLength is the number of bytes in the memory region;
// Byte is the value to be searched for
// maxBytes is the maximum number of bytes that are to be copied
// Returns: the number of occurrences of Byte found in the memory region

uint32_t findOccurrencesOfByte(uint32_t *const pOffsets,
                               const uint8_t *const blockAddress,
                               uint32_t blockLength, uint8_t Byte,
                               uint32_t maxBytes) {
  uint32_t count, read;
  count = 0;

  for (read = 0; read < blockLength && read < maxBytes; read++) {
    if (*(blockAddress + read) == Byte) {
      *(pOffsets + count) = read;
      count++;
    } // if
  } // for

  return count;
} // findOccurrencesOfByte
```

I'm not sure how to implement a condition that if `maxBytes == 3` and there are more than 3 occurrences it would stop after recording 3 times. I'm also still new to pointers and not sure if what I did is correct.

Comment: Pleas tell us what you tried, and what happens or errors in your code.

Comment: OT:  regarding `read`  This is a well known C library function, exposed via the header file: `unistd.h`  If you have not included that header file, then the code will work as expected,  However; in general, should not used C library function names for variable names.  Suggest using `index` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pointer code is correct.

You should be comparing `count` to `maxBytes`, not `read`.

```
  for (read = 0; read < blockLength && count < maxBytes; read++) {
    if (*(blockAddress + read) == Byte) {
      *(pOffsets + count) = read;
      count++;
    } // if
  } // for
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was it